# Are all contact lenses vegan?

Tags: veganism, health, is-it-vegan, animal-experimentation

It has been asked before whether things (such as [sugar](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/39/115), [water](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/293/115), [tea](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/447/115) or [condoms](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/533/115)) that do not obviously involve the use of animal derivatives might or not be vegan. Here my question is about contact lenses. Are all of them vegan? Do any of them use any products that have been tested on animals?

Comment: U should know about the difference of adulteration,vegan,  non-vegan.Sugar,water have nothing with vegan, non-vegan issue.**This is limited to some places**.[Sugar is treated with bone char in US only.] In some places these are treated with animal products only.In edible oils,oil extracted from animal fats are used by low quality manufacturers. U should consider ingredients,rep, quality of the manufacturers before purchasing.But u never know adulteration may happen. It is not compulsory to use animal products in manufacture of the above products.  [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] It is a method followed by some manufacturers to make quick money and don't give a thing about animal creulty.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there are no animal products involved in the production of contact-lenses. Whether they are vegan is debatable though and depends heavily on your definition of vegan.

The **trouble with lenses is that they are often being tested on animals**. While laws vary from country to country, there are countries and companies that do not test their lenses on animals and advertise so - you should be able to find them with a simple Google search. Unfortunately, as with many other products, most of the producers use at least some animal testing and so if the welfare of animals is an issue for you, you should always investigate the brand you intend to purchase.